# How do I see my deleted answers?

Tags: support, search, deleted-answers

It's happened a few times that I recall writing an answer on a topic but can't find it later. I think it happens when the question was deleted -- for example, if the answer has score 0 and the user deleted the question, or if the answer had 0 score and the question had negative score and the [Roomba](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243778/expanding-the-roomba-to-auto-delete-self-accepted-answered-questions-with-low-vi) removed it.

(Although my memory could be playing tricks, such as when I'm misremembering -- sometimes I write part of an answer, become dissatisfied with it, and discard the draft. But there's simply no way to recover the content in that scenario.)

Is there an easy way for me to find these answers? I have the privilege that lets me view deleted content, but only if I happen to find a link to it -- I'm not aware of a mechanism that lets me *search* or readily list things that are deleted. (Except in the case that I voted to delete something, in which case I can see it in the Delete tab under Votes.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. At high privilege levels (and I don't think there are any rep-related privileges you don't have), your deleted answers should normally appear in your "answers" tab of your activity page:

   [image: Deleted answer on answer tab]

   That shading is for a deleted answer.

   I don't remember when that happened for me. [Edit: Actually, it turns out this is really only useful for moderators]

   At lower privilege levels at the bottom of the same page there's the deleted recent answers link:

   [image: Deleted recent answer on answer tab]
2. Search. This should be more useful. Try: `user:nnnn deleted:yes`  (where nnnn is your ID number, 22311 in your case) or just `user:me deleted:yes`. You can refine this in various ways. This may be better for your purposes.
3. I expect you can get them with the SE data explorer (`data.stackexchange.com`). I found some queries that purport to do it but the few I checked out didn't quite work right (there may be one that does already). If you're happy to write your own SQL (I think SEDE uses t-SQL) you may be able to do it this way. However, SEDE only updates once a week so it won't find ones from the last few days.

Comment: Ah! I didn't know about the `deleted` advanced search option!

Comment: Hmm. I have one "deleted recent answer" (that I see when I click on "deleted recent answers") but it does not appear in the overall list of my answers (as in your first figure)... The search works great though; I did not know about it either.

Comment: @amoeba thanks, I'll mention that in the answer

Comment: @Sycorax thanks for that improvement

Comment: Only mods can see all of the deleted posts in the tab of the user page.

Comment: @gung Ah, okay. Thanks.